# Count column status transition with sqlite

Tags: sql, sqlite, transition, status

I need to count how many times a boolean column have changed to NO for each agent. Or how many times transitioned from YES to NO for each agent (whatever is easier)
Example:

[image: Table Example]

Expected result:
agent_A, 2 
agent_B, 0

Comment: Does 2 consecutive NO count as 1 or as 2?

Comment: count as 1 jarlh

Comment: Then my query doesn't work...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, you need the previous value and cumulative sum.  SQLite doesn't support window functions, so these are tricky.

```
select t.*,
       (select t2.status
        from t t2
        where t2.agent = t.agent and t2.datescan < t.datescan
        order by t2.datescan desc
        limit 1
       ) as prev_status
from t;
```

Next, you need to identify the changes and a cumulative sum of them:

```
with tt as (
      select t.*,
             (select t2.status
              from t t2
              where t2.agent = t.agent and t2.datescan < t.datescan
              order by t2.datescan desc
              limit 1
             ) as prev_status
      from t
     )
select tt.*,
       (select count(*)
        from tt tt2
        where tt2.agent = tt.agent and tt2.datescan < t.datescan and
              tt2.status = 'NO' and tt2.prev_status = 'YES'
      ) as counter
from tt;
```

Comment: Nice one, and very fast response for such complex query. Although "with" did not work on sqlite3 (not sure why). I managed creating a view called tt and adding "group by tt.agent" in the end of query. Thank you, I had struggled with it for hours.

Comment: Is it possible that we are not going to use subquery? I meet a similar problem, and I am using Hive and Presto. But none of them supports subquery in the platform I use.

Comment: @Wedoso . . . Ask a *new* question with appropriate sample data, desired results, and explanation of what you want to do.  SQLite <> Hive or Presto -- nowhere close.